# Negative margin bigger than view's height on pre lollipop devices

Tags: android, margin

It seems like it is not possible to assign a negative value bigger than view's dimensions. For example, lets say I have the following layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_marginTop="-2dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/closeIV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_close_white_24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/closeIV"
            android:text="GALERÍA"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <View
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pictureIV"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/galleryRV"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pictureIV"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
    <View
        android:layout_below="@id/pictureIV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/grid_layout_separator"
        android:layout_height="10dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

If I set the top margin of the toolbar bigger than the toolbar's height, let's say -200dp, the output in postlollipop devices would be the toolbar fully hidden, 144dp of the image view hidden and the recyclerview would be stretched by 200dp, you can see a similar behaviour on Instagram's gallery. But in pre lollipop devices the output would be, the toolbar fully hidden, the imageview on top and the recyclerview stretched by 56 dp. So it seems that it is not possible to set the negative margin bigger than the toolbar's height, is there a workaround to have a similar behaviour in prelollipop devices?

Comment: but why are you using negative margin?

Comment: I'm trying to implement something like the instagram's gallery, if you check instagram, once your finger pass the recyclerview/listview's height it will strech and hide the toolbar while moving the image upwards, i could simulate the same behaviour on post lollipop using negative margins on the toolbar, but it's not working on pre... how would you achive this behavior?

Comment: I think that is known as collapsing toolbar. Not sure but you can check it if that what you want

Comment: I alredy did but i think the behaviour it's different